# Android locationManager requestLocationUpdates not called

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2, locationlistener

I'm making an android application which keeps track of your location to eventually draw your route on a google map. Everything seems to be working except for one thing which, strangely enough, did work before. I think I did not change anything that matters to the function call and most examples I found did it the same way I did.

In my onCreate method I do the following:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
```

later i call upon the LocationListener:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
```

but somehow this does not get called. Tried logging everywhere, everything returned a value except for the ones in the `onLocationChanged`. Doesn't work with `GPS_PROVIDER` either

All the relevant code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Tell the program to get location updates every 2 seconds(2000ms)
        // I sadly don't get called..
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
    }

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            System.out.Println("I'm just here for debugging purposes");
            System.out.Println("Sadly I don't appear in Logcat");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

    };
```

Comment: If it's an option, you may want to look at Google's Fused Location API available in the Play Services library. It's simple, fast, and (from my experience) more reliable than trying to do everything related to location manually and in a way that works well across all versions of Android. https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yep, did that. Got `FINE_LOCATION`, `COARSE_LOCATION`, `MAPS_RECEIVE`, `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `INTERNET` and `READ_GSERVICES`.